# Change Label content based on ListBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxItemsList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Button Content="Add me!" Click="AddItem" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description}"  />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The ObservableCollection objects have several properties, including `uniqueID`, `name`, `description`, `colour`, `flavour`. Depending on the selected item in the ListBox, I would like to populate some Labels with the selected item's properties. Additionally, each item's Button should perform a unique action (i.e. add one of the relevant items to an Array) however I cannot figure out how to send a unique argument to the AddItem() method. I thought that this would be a common use case, but I cannot find anything by googling.

Thanks.

Comment: `I would like the details of some Labels to display the selected item's properties`... `details of some Labels to display`??

Comment: Thank you, I reworded the sentence.

Comment: @jberger: Actually I am not using an MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Depending on the selected item in the ListBox I would like the details
>   of some Labels to display the selected item's properties

You could bind the ListBox.SelectedItem to a DependencyProperty and then just bind that property to those Labels.

> Additionally, each item's Button should perform a unique action (i.e.
>   add one of the relevant items to an Array) however I cannot figure out
>   how to send a unique argument to the AddItem() method.

You could add the Item id to the Button.Tag

```
<Button Content="Add me!" Click="AddItem" Tag={Binding Path=id} />
```

Then just get the button tag on the sender

```
public void button_clicked(object sender, event e) {
    int id = ((Button)sender).Tag as Int32;
    ...
}
```

**Edit**: You can also bind the full Item instead of just the Id to the button Tag.

Comment: Alternatively, you could expose an ICommand property from the item and bind the Button Command attribute to that (google DelegateCommand for more details).